# Javascript: magic with replacing a whitespace in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I cannot remove a whitespace in a string if a variable contains that value:

```
var groupingSeparator = ' ';
'123 456'.replace( new RegExp( groupingSeparator ), '' );

>>> as result: '123 456'
```

But I can do it without a separate variable:

```
'123 456'.replace( new RegExp( ' ' ), '' );

>>> as result: '123456'
```

I need this variable because it could also contain another value (comma, point and go on).
So why we have a different behavior in the "equals" code examples? How to solve it?

EDIT:
So it does not work for me locally because the value of the groupSeparator variable is not a simple whitespace. It is '\u00A0'.

Comment: `'123 456'.replace( new RegExp( groupingSeparator ), '' );` yields `123456`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right. Maybe it is an issue with my local code...

Comment: Don't forget to assign the replaced value: `str = str.replace( new RegExp( g ), '' );`

Comment: So it does not work for me locally because the value of the groupSeparator variable is not simple whitespace. It is '\u00A0'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s` as separator - it matches whitespaces. Note that you need to add "\" to use it with `RegExp` constructor. I've also added `g` flag (global) to replace all matches in given string

```js
var groupingSeparator = '\\s';
var text = '123\u00a0456'
console.log("before", text)
var result = text.replace( new RegExp( groupingSeparator , "g"), '' );
console.log("after", result)
```